# Gatsby markdown images are stuck with blurred span

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby, mdxjs

I'm working with Gatsby, and I want to load my posts with images from markdowns.

I'm using this tutorial:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/

I get my "featuredImage" properly loaded and removed, and then blur span.

But the images inside markdown get loaded, but the blurred span stays on the page.

my `gatsby-config.js`

```
//https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Tzook Blog`,
    description: `My old blog in new gatsby`,
    author: `@tzookb`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/`
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1200
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`
  ],
}
```

See these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So it's the image inside `MDXRenderer`?

Comment: Yes, but I assume it passes through gatsby image process, but the span for some reason stays in..

Comment: Can you add your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: just added @ksav

Comment: I think `gatsby-plugin-mdx` was the gatsby v1 compatible version. Try using `gatsby-mdx`

Comment: I see this on their repo: https://gatsby-mdx.netlify.com

Comment: Ugh sorry. I got my wires crossed. Does this help? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15486#issuecomment-509405867

Comment: thanks @ksav, dont know why, but it works :) please post an answer so I could approve that with your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for this can be found in [cwgw's comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15486#issuecomment-510153237) on this [open gatsby issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15486):

> So digging a little deeper, it looks like Gatsby only looks for "subplugins" at one specific path, `options.plugins`.
>
> `gatsby-plugin-mdx` uses `options.gatsbyRemarkPlugins`. This is fine for transforming markdown as the plugin handles that itself, but Gatsby-specific api files like `gatsby-browser.js` don't get loaded because Gatsby doesn't know they exist.
>
> If you try this…

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
  options: {
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [ `gatsby-remark-images` ],
    plugins: [ `gatsby-remark-images` ],
  }
},
```

> …everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

ksav's solution works for me - In case anyone is confused, this is short for this syntax:
`{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [{ resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images' }],
        plugins: [{ resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images' }],
      },`

Where an object with key 'resolve' is used to specify the plugin name instead of simply passing it into the array as a string.